# Passing NSDictionary to function to add objects/keys but shows up empty in main()

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, nsdictionary

I'm new to Objective C and I'm having a problem with adding to my NSMutableDictionary. I have a Thing class that contains the following method.

```
-(BOOL) addThing:(Thing*)myThing withKey:(NSString*)key inDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary*) myDictionary
{
    if(!myDictionary) { //lazy initialization
       myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
       [myDictionary setObject:myThing forKey:key];
       return YES;
    } 
    else {
       if(![myDictionary allKeysForObject: _monster]) {
         [myDictionary setObject:record forKey:key];
         return YES;
       }
       else {
         NSLog(@"The username %@ already exists!", _monster);
         return NO;
    }
  }
```

}

But when I call it in my main() the dictionary still shows up empty.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;

    Thing *foo = [Thing thingWithName:@"Frankenstein" andFeature:@"green"];
    [foo addThing:foo withKey:@"foo" inDictionary:myDictionary];

    if([myDictionary count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"I'm not empty!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Dictionary is empty");
    }

    //Prints out "Dictionary is empty"

}
return 0;
```

}

If I do count check directly inside my addThing method, it will print "I'm not empty!". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only initialising the local variable `myDictionary` in `addThing:withKey:inDictionary`.
In order to be able to affect the NSDictionary you are passing as argument, you must indeed pass a `NSDictionary **` to your function, and treat it as the pointer it is, that is, use it as `*myDictionary`

Something that does indeed work would be:

```
- (BOOL) addThing:(id)thing withKey:(NSString *)key inDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary **)myDictionary{
   if(!*myDictionary && key && thing){
      *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
      [*myDictionary setObject:thing forKey:key];
      return YES;
   } else {
     // Removed this code as it doesn't really matter to your problem
     return NO;
   }
}
```

and call it like (note that the address of the dict variable is being passed instead of just the plain variable):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict;
[foo addThing:foo withKey:@"key" inDictionary:&dict]
```

This will indeed turn dict into a non-nil dictionary, provided you didn't pass a nil `key` or `thing`, that will contain object `foo` for key `@"key"`.

I tested and got no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is objective C and not plain C, your call to the method is still a call by value, not by reference.  Your method call  [foo addThing:foo withKey:@"foo" inDictionary:myDictionary] creates a copy of the pointer myDictionary, and sends it to your method.  The Dictionary is created and then lost, as there is no mechanism here to copy it back to the real myDictionary that lives in your main function.  Look up call by reference and call by value if you're still not sure.  The myDictionary that's created in your addThing method is a copy of the original myDictionary and does not affect your global one.

Comment: Just a side note - it being a copy only affects the creation of the object:       myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];  If you move this code to your main function and create it there, all will work as you intend.

Comment: I understand your explanation of pass by reference vs value. However, I tried changing my parameters to (NSMutableDictionary*) to (NSMutableDictionary**) so that it points to the pointer. But when I change the rest of the code to *login, XCode complains in my main method that I'm "Sending 'NSMutableDictionary' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSMutableDictionary *_autoreleasing *'".